# Exporting Outlook Email to Excel (Used code from StackExchange)

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to create a program that migrates Outlook emails to excel. I found a solution to this problem about a year ago on this site, and everything worked fine until the body of the email changed and I had to update the code. Came back here to Frankenstein some code together, but am now getting errors that go over my head in VBA.

The emails look like this (the numbers are added for reference and to make the structure the same, they are not in the emails):

1. Name:
2. Do you currently reside in the United States?
3. Address:
4. City:
5. State:
6. Zip Code:
7. Phone:
8. Email:
9. Citizenship:
10. Grade:
11. Essay Word Count:
12. School / Organization Name: Teacher Name: Teacher Email: Is your school / sponsoring organization based in the United States?  School / Organization Address:  School / Organization City:  School / Organization State:  School / Organization Zip Code:  School / Organization Phone:  School / Organization Email:  How did you find out about this contest?  Essay Document:

The old code worked up until the paragraph. So I found new code to run through paragraph and just added it on

Old code:

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim vPara As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim aa As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim sLink As String
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = " " 'the path of the workbook- HERE IS WHERE YOU CHANGE THE LOCATION OF THE SPREADSHEET

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
sText = olItem.Body
vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
vPara = Split(sText, Chr(13))
'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
rCount = rCount + 1

'Check each line of text in the message body
For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Name:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Do you currently reside in the United States?") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address 2:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "City:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "State:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Zip Code:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Country:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Phone:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Email:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("J" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Citizenship:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Grade:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("L" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Essay Word Count:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("M" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
```

Here is the new paragraph part that I added

```
For aa = 0 To UBound(vPara)
    If InStr(1, vPara(aa), "School / Organization Name: ") > 0 Then
        rCount = xlSheet.Range("N" & xlSheet.Rows.Count)
        rCount = rCount + 1
        vText = Split(vPara(i), Chr(58))
        vItem = Split(vText(2) & vText(3), ChrW(34))
        xlSheet.Range("N" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(1), "Teacher Name: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(4), "Teacher Email", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(5), " Is your school / sponsoring    organization based in the United States?", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("R" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(6), " School / Organization Address: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("S" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(7), " School / Organization City: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("T" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(8), " School / Organization State: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("U" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " School / Organization Zip Code: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("V" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " School / Organization Phone: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("W" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " School / Organization Email: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("X" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " How did you find out about this contest? ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("Y" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " Essay Document: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("Z" & rCount) = Trim(vText(10))
    End If

Next aa
xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

First, does this even attempt to do what I am doing? Second off, when I debug it in VBA, it throws an error at Next olItem, saying "Invalid Next control variable reference". I tried to find what that meant online, and it might be an open loop? But I close the if. I only have experience coding with Python and Java, so it may be a syntax problem and my unfamiliarity.

Full Code
    Option Explicit

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim vPara As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim oRng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim sLink As String
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String =  "C:\Users\Awardsintern\Documents\StudentInfo.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook-  HERE IS WHERE YOU CHANGE THE LOCATION OF THE SPREADSHEET

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
sText = olItem.Body
vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
vPara = Split(sText, Chr(13))
'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
rCount = rCount + 1

'Check each line of text in the message body
For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Name:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Do you currently reside in the United States?") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Address 2:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "City:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "State:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Zip Code:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Country:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Phone:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("I" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Email:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("J" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Citizenship:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("K" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Grade:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("L" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If
    If InStr(1, vText(i), "Essay Word Count:") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("M" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

For i = 0 To UBound(vPara)
    If InStr(1, vPara(i), "School / Organization Name: ") > 0 Then
        rCount = xlSheet.Range("N" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        rCount = rCount + 1
        vText = Split(vPara(i), Chr(58))
        vItem = Split(vText(2) & vText(3), ChrW(34))
        xlSheet.Range("N" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        xlSheet.Range("O" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(1), "Teacher Name: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("P" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(4), "Teacher Email", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("Q" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(5), " Is your school / sponsoring    organization based in the United States?", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("R" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(6), " School / Organization Address: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("S" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(7), " School / Organization City: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("T" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(8), " School / Organization State: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("U" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " School / Organization Zip Code: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("V" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " School / Organization Phone: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("W" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " School / Organization Email: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("X" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " How did you find out about this contest? ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("Y" & rCount) = Trim(Replace(vText(9), " Essay Document: ", ""))
        xlSheet.Range("Z” & rCount) = Trim(vText(10))
    End If

Next i
xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Edit rolled back. You may accept the answer and ask a new question.  See  What should I do when someone answers my question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305272/what-to-do-when-a-user-asks-a-question-and-keeps-updating-with-new-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two For Next loops with "i" as your counter.

```
For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
```

and

```
For i = 0 To UBound(vPara)
```

That is the source of your error.  It appears that you originally had the second loop counting with "aa".

Comment: Hi! I took your suggestions and put them in. I changed my question above because I ran into some other problem! If you have a chance, please take a look above.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this site, so let me ask a question that may seem noob. It sounds like what you said is that my answer worked, but instead of accepting it as the answer to your question, you changed the question and now need a different answer to a different, but related question. I see how doing that saves time since the base information is the same. It would be nice if they had a means for awarding the answer and then maybe branching another Q off the original post.  Anyway... I'll look through it.

Comment: See  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305272/what-to-do-when-a-user-asks-a-question-and-keeps-updating-with-new-questions also http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hi nfloria! I didn't realize what I did was against stackoverflow meta rules. I am also new to this site! The reason I did not accept your answer as the best answer to my question was because it related to a copy and paste issue that was only present in half of my original code. When I copied the full code over I forgot to update that I had switched the iterator variable to aa, I am so sorry for the confusion. I can put your question as the answer, since it did technically answer my original question (that is still present in the first post).